# How to convert map into json using Moshi

Tags: java, json, hashmap, moshi

I am trying to convert Map into json using moshi but I couldn't any find any help.

```
 val attentionNumbepAdapter: JsonAdapter<Map<String, Employee>> = moshi
                .adapter(Types.newParameterizedType(Map::class.java, String::class.java, Employee::class.java))
```

but it gives `IllegalArgumentException`. Any idea how to correctly approach this problem?

Comment: Post the exception message and stacktrace.

Answer (score 5):

Probably little bit late with the answer, still here it is.

Sample method to convert Map to Json using moshi:

```
  private <K, V> String objectsMapToJson(Class<K> key, Class<V> value, Object json) {
    return moshi()
        .adapter(Types.newParameterizedType(Map.class, key, value))
        .toJson(json);
  }
```

Usage:

```
      Map<String, Employee> employeeMap = new HashMap<>();

      //populate map with some data

      String json = objectsMapToJson(String.class, Employee.class, employeeMap);
```

Hope it helps.